# TripleDES encryption in universal app c# WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, tripledes

```
public static string tripleDESEncryptor(string toEncrypt, string keyString)
{

    var crypt = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.TripleDesEcb);
    IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(toEncrypt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(keyString, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    CryptographicKey key = crypt.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);            
    var sigBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(key, buffer);  // throws exception here
    string signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(sigBuffer);
    return signature;
}
```

This throws an InvalidCastException and I can't seem to figure out why or what I am doing wrong.

The keyString is of length 24.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any details in the exception? Message, data, stacktrace? Have you tried using `CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(24)` and comparing its result to your own key-buffer (actual type, length, kind of content)?

Comment: Message : Specified cast is not valid.
Inner Exception : null.
Stack Trace : at Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicEngine.Sign(CryptographicKey key, IBuffer data)

Comment: @PieterWitvoet : The key-buffer is showing length and capacity as 24, same as on using CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(24). The buffer is showing length and capacity as 36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for helping,this worked out for me -

```
public static string tripleDESEncryptor(string toEncrypt, string keyString)
{
   var crypt = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.TripleDesEcbPkcs7);

            IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(toEncrypt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
            IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(keyString, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

            CryptographicKey key = crypt.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);

            IBuffer signed = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buffer, null);

            string signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signed);
            return signature;
}
```

Comment: hi @nipun.birla , I tried the same thing in my windows phone application, But getting an exception pn createsymmetrickey method " Value does not fall within the expected range.". Can you help me

Comment: @asitis what's the length of your key string?

Comment: hi , key length is 20.

Comment: @asitis Can you try with a key length of multiple of 8 if that does not effect your requirement